# Como enviar post com o Request Payload

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$url = 'https://www.habbo.com.br';
$email = 'exemplo@google.com';
$pass = '123456';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd().'/login.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd().'/login.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email='.$email.'&password='$pass.);
```

Quando eu envio o formulário de login no site `https://www.habbo.com.br/` usando a função Network do Google Chrome (no DevTools) no header enviado, mostra `Request Payload`. Como eu envio um formulário usando esse `Request Payload`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa enviar um JSON para o site do Habbo, porque é isso que ele espera de você:

```
$data = json_encode(['email'=>$email, 'password'=>$pass]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

E ai você tem que enviar um header informando isso:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
               array('Content-Type:application/json',
                      'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
               );
```

Veja exemplos aqui:

- http://lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079135/how-to-post-json-data-with-php-curl
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271140/curl-and-php-how-can-i-pass-a-json-through-curl-by-put-post-get